# Actionscript 2 advanced collision detection

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, collision, hittest

I'm wondering what the best way to go about advanced collision detection in AS2 would be. I don't mean bounding boxes, because that's fine. Specifically how do I stop the player from moving in one direction when colliding with something.

Imagine a top-down shooter. Basically I'm looking for how the collision detections were achieved in a game similar to this: http://ninjakiwi.com/Games/Action/Play/SAS-Zombie-Assault-2.html

I have an array that keeps track of the direction the player is currently moving(up, down, left, right). I also have four variables allowing the player to move in each direction if the corresponding variable is true. When the player collides with a movieclip in the collision array I set the variables relating to the directions he is moving to false, so he can't keep moving in the direction he was going when he collided with the object. The problem arises when the player is moving diagonally(two directions) and collides with something that he should be able to continue moving in one direction in. Example:

[image]

The play should be able to move in the up direction, but cannot.

Another problem is that the variables determining wether or not the player can move are set back to true when the opposite direction's key is pressed(ie. able to move right is set to true when left is pressed, since we've moved in the opposite direction). So in the previous example if you were not to move diagonally and simply move right, then hold right down while moving up until you aren't touching the object anymore you wouldn't be able to move right because the left key wasn't pressed.

It seems like I'm over complicating things, is there any way besides individually placing all walls that stop the player from moving in one direction?(Ie. If the player touches this wall, stop moving right). <--- This way doesn't allow for randomly generated maps when objects are rotated. Or is there some way I can get around this using math depending on the object rotation?

What's the easiest way to hitTest? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted any code so it's hard to tell, but you're probably going about reacting to a collision the wrong way.

Rather than disabling movement if you collide with your wall, you should instead move the player to the outside of the wall if he collides with it.

Basically what you want to do is:

1. Keep track of where the player was *last frame*.
2. Check if the player is colliding with a wall *this frame*.
3. If he is, check where he was last frame to get an idea of which side of the wall he was on before the collision occurred. Use this information to reposition the player so that he is touching that face of the wall.

Comment: So basically keep track of the player's last position, and if a collision occurs, move him back to the previous position? This seems much easier but I still have one problem. When the player is colliding with an object, but can still move in one direction(like the example before), since a hittest is still occuring he'll keep moving back to the old position, even though he can move in another direction.

Comment: @MikeHunter You're missing one detail. Don't move to the previous position - you should just be using that information to determine which side the player came from before hitting the wall. With that information you should move the player so he is touching the wall from that side. This will give it a realistic feel of the player being right up against the wall unable to move further. As for not being able to move, you should get rid of the logic that disabled the player's movement if a collision is occurring. That is not required once you implement my steps.

Comment: @MikeHunter If you move to the previous position you'll get cases where when you move 10 pixels and collide with the wall, you'll return to 10 pixels away from the wall which will give odd results.

Comment: Right, so we're getting closer. I'm just having trouble with determining where to place him(and how exactly). I'm able to find out what direction he was moving in by comparing his last position with his current, but not if that direction was the one specifically from stopping him from moving. Do you think it's possible to provide some code? Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MikeHunter If you for example work out that he was directly left of the tile (lower than the top of the tile, higher than the bottom and to the left of its centre), the new position of the player would be something like this (assuming that the registration point of the player and the tile are both centred): `player.x = tile.x - (tile.width / 2) - (player.width / 2); player.y = oldPlayerY;`

Comment: @MikeHunter The main trick with collision detection and reactions is understanding the relationship between where the player was and where it is when a collision occurs. This relationship defines which direction the player was moving and which side the collision happened on. Generally there is a velocity associated with object, which makes where it came from easier to work out; a negative x velocity for example would mean it's travelling from the right. This saves you needing to store old positions.

Comment: Alright, I understand. However since we are still colliding with the tile when we are moved to the edge of it, we can't move in an upwards direction as we are constantly being set to our previous y position. You can take a look at my code here: http://pastebin.com/KcreKa2E

Comment: @MikeHunter Sure, so what's happening here is that you're considering just touching the wall as being a collision. I consider a collision to be when the player is actually *inside* the wall (passing into it). This way, when you're moved to be just next to it, it's not considered a collision.